# How to execute a MATLAB script in VBA

Tags: vba, matlab, confirmation, createobject, external-application

I want to run a MATLAB script using VBA. I tried running the following code

```
Set Matlab = CreateObject("Matlab.Application")
result = Matlab.Execute("path to the script")
MsgBox (result)
```

But it doesn't return anything in the msgbox, nor was the MATLAB workspace modified. How can I know it ran the script?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether the script ran, you can have it create an empty file with a timestamp.

```matlab
fclose(fopen([pwd, date], 'w')); % This only shows the current date
```

If you see this file after running the VBA command, it means the script ran.

The reason you don't see changes in the workspace is probably because it opens a new MATLAB instance to run your script in.

Comment: how can i view the output of matlab script if it is creating another instance?

Comment: This is a different question, but the answer is essentially the same - save it to a file, don't print it to the screen.